# Error message when trying to iterate list in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my Model I have this list of strings:

```
public static List<string> listOfNames = new List<string>();
```

And in the Controller I have this Action:

```
public ActionResult NameInput()
    {
        NameModel.prepareList();
        return View("NameInput", NameModel.listOfNames);
    }
```

And in the top of the View I have this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Exercise_3.Models.NameModel>
```

I guess this is where it's wrong, but I don't know what to use instead. This line was OK from the beginning, when I had a list of objects, but now I just want to use a list of strings.

The error message I get when I run the application is the following:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Exercise_3.Models.NameModel]'.

Comment: can you try changing `@model IEnumerable<Exercise_3.Models.NameModel>` to `@model IEnumerable<String>` ?

Comment: The model your passing to the view is `List<string>` so in the view it needs to be `@model IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Thanks both of you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model you are sending to the view is  the `listOfNames` property value of `NameModel`. The `listOfNames` property is of type `List<string>`. but in your razor view you specified the model type as `IEnumerable<Exercise_3.Models.NameModel>`. Those are not matching.

You may update your razor view to use `List<string>` as the model type

```
@model List<string>
<h1>Items</h1>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <h2>@item</h2>
}
```